# Atlassian Crucible/Fisheye: Can't browse changesets; strange debug message

Tags: svn, fisheye, crucible

I'm running Atlassian Crucible/Fisheye and all of a sudden none of my users can browse changesets for any of the configured repositories.  The only clue I have as to the cause of this is the following message from the debug log:

`2010-10-26 14:00:24,378 DEBUG [btpool0-25] svn.SvnSCMModule SvnAuth-prompt - System prompted for user crucible, which does not match configured username ******`

(I replaced the actual username with asterisks, but rest assured that there is one there; it's the username that the repository is configured with in Fisheye.)  I Googled this message but was unable to find any relevant information.

The message is displayed whenever anyone tries to add content to a review using the "Browse Changesets," "Explore Repositories" or "Search for Files" options.  Oddly, browsing using the source browser still works.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that authentications seem to be cached when you use the HTTP interface to connect to SVN.  I was trying to connect to a single SVN server using multiple different accounts (for separate repositories), and the cached credentials were causing this mismatch.  Switching all of the repositories to use the same account solved the issue.